# How to find out if any class from dependency is being used in the maven application?

Tags: spring-boot, dependencies, maven-2

I have a huge maven application with nearly about 100 maven dependencies in the pom.xml file.

One starter dependency is downloading log4j.jar which is not required at all. So, is there an easy to find in order to make sure no class from a particular jar is being used so that we can exclude it directly from starter dependency as shown below.

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>example-artifact</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Basically I want to exclude the jar which I am not using at all but simply comes as a transitive dependency.

Comment: Try using `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: Hi @crizzis, I understand the above gives the structure but I am more worried about useless jars that come along with direct dependencies

Comment: mvn dependency:tree helped, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More specifically, this will show you exactly what you're asking:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html

Comment: Maven resolves the dependencies using the nearest first resolution